# Notation for symbol keys in vim

Tags: vim

When setting up key bindings, key identifiers such as `<CR>` or `<right>` work fine.

Eg, `nmap <S-Enter> O<Esc>`

But how can you enter symbol keys? such as `^` or `$`. I looked into `:h key-notation` but it only gives a few often used symbols. (not all)

Answer (score 4):

No special notation needed:

```
nnoremap $ :echo "But I don't want to go to the end!"<CR>
```